# PHP Framework Zend not Working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

When I try to load it some error occurs that prevents the rest of the page from loading.

My file basically looks like this:

```
use Zend\Form\Form;

include 'Zend/Form/Form.php';

$form = new Form();

// Page Content
```

What am I doing wrong?

PHP Errors:

Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Form\Fieldset' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/contest-guess-image/Zend/Form/Form.php on line 24

Comment: The page dosen't load.  It does load without the $form=new Form(); line

Comment: Anything in the error log?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Posted errors.

Comment: There is your problem - the form module cannot be found.

Comment: The Zend folder and file above are in the same directory.  How can it not find it?

Comment: `\Zend\Form\Form.php` shows the slash at the beginning. php will try to find the file from the root of the disk. Do you have it in your code? And also, why do you use `Zend\Form\Form.php` instead of `Zend/Form/Form.php`?

Comment: @Cheery I just tried it both ways...  Unix vs W$

Comment: @BAR look at line 18 of `contest-guess-image.php`. Is it the the same include line that you showed? The error definitely shows `\\`

Comment: @Cheery I changed the \ to / and lost three of the errors.  Posting a new error now.

Comment: @BAR `Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Form\Fieldset'` - probably the required namespace is not added in `Form.php`

Comment: @Cheery I really doubt the dev's of Zend would over look that, don't you think?

Comment: @BAR yes, but your configuration of application might affect it. May be you modified `Form.php`. May be your application missing some vendor files. But the error tells that it can not find that class and error is not related to the code shown in the question.

Comment: I didn't touch it, honestly.  I would be shocked if a mature framework with unit tests would have failed like this.

Comment: @BAR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884819/fatal-error-class-zend-form-element-not-found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use ZF2 without autoloading. Composer makes this easy, if you're not using composer you'll need to [setup the ZF2 standard autoloader yourself](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html#manual-configuration) before using any other ZF2 classes.

Comment: How about ZF1 ?  I don't want a heavyweight loader when all I want are the forms classes.  I would have gone with some other forms library for php if I hadn't found ZF's syntax to be so much better.. almost about to roll-my-own...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a heavyweight autoloader, composer class map autoloader's is about as fast as they come, and only involves adding one line of code to the top of your script.

Comment: One line of code is nice, but I don't see where that one line is in your link.  I do see multiple lines, so where is that magic line?  Please add it to your answer for everyone's benefit and I can accept your answer.

Comment: Here's the magic line for composer: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading - but you should read the whole page if you're going to go down that route (which I would recommend).

Comment: The one-liner does require work with 'composer' before being useable. Thank you for the help!